# First row of table is not shown in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching my rows from database into webpage, but it is omitting the first row from database and showing results from 2nd row. what should I do to fix it? my code:

```
<?php
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysql_select_db("try_test");
 $query = "SELECT id, q_id, question,ans_options FROM test1";
 $result=mysql_query($query);

if($record=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


   echo $record['q_id']. ". " ;

   echo $record['question']."<br/>";

}
else{
     echo "error";
}

while($record=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<input type=radio>" ;
    echo $record['ans_options']."<br/>";
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or pdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fetching the 1st row, but its not followed by Radio button . So may be you are not able to read it. Comment the below part in your code then you will get all the rows

```
if($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $record['q_id']. ". " ;
  echo $record['question']."<br/>"; 
} else{ echo "error";}
```

If you still need this part of the code, Please let us know the purpose of it.

Comment: if I removed this then its working. But I need this code because question needs to be printed once, whereas ans_options are four and needs to be printed as four entries.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use mysql_fetch_array more than once. Because, It fetches the row 1st and move the pointer to the next record. Than second time when you use that function it start fetching from that pointer`s position. So, You will not have your 1st record. Hope this help. I think @Abdulla Nilam has written the right code.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
if($record=mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

you read the first line. So your while loop starts add the second line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysql_select_db("try_test");
 $query = "SELECT id, q_id, question,ans_options FROM test1";
 $result=mysql_query($query);

if($record=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

   echo $record['q_id']. ". " ;


     echo $record['question']."<br/>";

   mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
      while($record=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ?>
        <input type=radio><?php echo $record["ans_options"]; ?>
        <br/>
}
<?php
}
else{
     echo "error";
}

?>
```

bro can you try this and see.

Comment: I used mysql_data_seek($result, 0) this statement, now its showing it correctly. thanks.

Comment: when you check through if its point to array [0], so next point will be start with 1. so first will omitted by default. Think you learned the case